# Передача данных между сервисом и activity (fragment'ом)

Tags: android, android-service

Пишу приложение-менеджер для скачивания файлов с сети. Только начал освоение темы сервисов. Закачка файла будет вестись как раз через сервис. Закачек одновременно может быть несколько. Вопросы:

**1)** Правильно ли я понимаю, что 1 экземпляр класса сервис = 1 закачке?

**2)** Во время скачивания файла обновляется статус и прочая инфа о закачке в активити. Общение между активити (фрагментом) и сервисом происходит через intent'ы (каждую секунду обновлять статус). Не накладно ли посылать с такой регулярностью постоянно экземпляр класса Download (куда включена инфа о закачке) в активити (фрагмент)? Или можно сделать это более выгодным способом?

Comment: Закачку лучше реализовать через AsyncTask, где есть специальный метод, который может отдавать информацию о прогрессе выполнения.

Comment: Закачка должна работать и при выходе из приложения и при свернутом приложении. Использовать AsyncTask в сервисе - а что это меняет, если мне все равно нужно каким то образом "общаться" с активити?

Comment: Окей, тогда другое решение. Активити биндится к сервису и регистрируется у него (реализовать методы биндинга и хранения ссылки на активити). Сервис запускает потоки скачивания (кстати, сервис он всегда один инстанс, так что реализуйте много потоков) и через ссылку Активити сообщает ей прогресс. Когда Активити закрывается, то она должна снять регистрацию. Как то так)

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Вопрос по Intentservice'у - раз в нем реализован функционал по завершению задачи, то правильно ли будет использовать его для одной отдельной задачи?